# OSX app crashing: code signature invalid

Tags: objective-c, macos, code-signing, lazarus, freepascal

I have an OSX app that I distribute outside the AppStore. Therefor I sign it with the according certificate (Developer ID Application Certificate).

The app itself is written in Freepascal (Lazarus) and has a dependency lib, written in C++, which I also sign. I also change the path of the lib to be relative to the app by using install_name_tool and prefixing the path with @loader_path. Works like a charm for me locally.

The app (as reported to me) works OK on OSX 10.11.6, but crashes on OSX 10.10.5, saying:
Library not loaded: @loader_path/libMyAPP.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/USER/Downloads/MyAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAPP
Reason: no suitable image found. Did find:
/Users/Steve/Downloads/MyAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/libMyAPP.dylib: code signature invalid for '/Users/Steve/Downloads/MyAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/libMyAPP.dylib'

/Users/Steve/Downloads/MyAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/libMyAPP.dylib: code signature invalid for '/Users/Steve/Downloads/MyAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/libMyAPP.dylib'

Any pointers what might be going on? Is this really a code signing issue or something else? Thanks.

Comment: Didyou solve this - we hav a very similar issue, also wiht a 10.10.5 user...

Comment: I did. The problem with mac libs is that when they are built, they have an absolute path written inside them. So you have to use install_name_tool to change the path to a relative one.

Comment: So it wasn't a code signing issue at all?

Comment: The message is somewhat misleading. Yes, codesigning is an issue, because the library is missing. The library however is missing, because it cannot be loaded. It cannot be loaded, because of OSX' architecture where the original path is being burned into each dylib.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same error with XCode 11/iPhone7 device and google firebase.

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher
  Referenced from:

...

Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signature invalid for

...

GTMSessionFetcher: stat() failed with errno=1

### Solution

try to remove pod and remove use_framework!

```
pod deintegrate
```

then remove use_framework!

```
  # use_frameworks!
```

then install again

```
pod install
```

Comment: Lifesaver solution.. :)